# Is Eclipse's Java's null object prediction wrong in this case?

Tags: java, eclipse, null-pointer

My Eclipse Oxygen tells me that there is a `Potential null pointer access: The variable list may be null at this location` at this code's line 7.
In my opinion there is no chance that either `list` or `list2` is null.

```
public static <T> boolean equalsLists(List<T> list, List<T> list2, Equals<T> equals)
    {
    if (list == list2)
        return true;
    if (list == null ^ list2 == null)
        return false;
    if (list.size() != list2.size()) //here eclipse highlights a Potential null pointer access for both list and list2
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++)
        if (equals == null && !equals(list.get(i), list2.get(i)) || equals != null && !equals.equals(list.get(i), list2.get(i)))
            return false;
    return true;
    }
```

EDIT: As I've written in my comment answering a comment, it's obvious that using an OR instead of a XOR will keep working, and I've tested that Eclipse correctly stop predicting a possible Null Pointer.
Maybe I've not been clear in my question. I'm not asking how to make Eclipse stop warning me but if there is a proper reason why Eclipse warns me.

Comment: You're writing a somewhat weird piece of code (I mean the XOR), so I guess it may be confused. Just use an OR, it would work anyway.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks for pointing that out. It's obvious that using an OR instead of a XOR will keep working, and I've tested that Eclipse correctly stop predict a possible Null Pointer. Maybe I've not been clear in my question. I'm not asking how to make Eclipse stop warning me but if there is a proper reason why Eclipse warns me.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the XOR operator `^`  instead of the standard or `||`? The default would be easier to read and also perform better because of short circuiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's mistaken. It hasn't understood that the combination of your initial `list == list2` early return with your subsequent XOR (`^`) check's early return rules out the possibility of either of them being `null` beyond that point.

---

*(I wouldn't be surprised if your average maintenance programmer looking at that code later tripped over it as well.)*

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is confused by your tricky code.   If you write it like this:

```
if (list == list2)
    return true;
if (list == null || list2 == null)
    return false;
```

then Eclipse is able to work it out.   (I checked with Eclipse 4.7.1 ...)

The problem is that `list == null ^ list2 == null` is `false` when both `list` and `list2` are `null`.  This case is dealt with in the previous `if` statement, but Eclipse's flow analysis is not capable of deducing that.

Comment: I was hoping that was the case (that it understands with `||`). Didn't have Eclipse handy to check (I don't use Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

In your case method would return true even if both lists are null unless that is a valid scenario for you. Ideally first line in your method should be the null check.

```
if (list == null || list2 == null)
    return false;
```